# auto-indent in Sublime Text 2 with Erlang after ->

Tags: erlang, sublimetext2, auto-indent

How to auto-indent in Sublime Text 2 with Erlang after -> ?

I found this page: http://sublimetext.userecho.com/topic/85708-fix-increaseindentpattern-for-erlang/

How to apply it?

Do I have to use some packages such as SublimErl?

Thanks!

---

Update:

Install Sublime-Erlang (https://github.com/fjl/Sublime-Erlang‎) and disable the Erlang package shipped with Sublime Text 2 is the most easy way.

Answer (score 1):

If the want to apply the new pattern that you linked to, than edit this file:

```
~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/Erlang/Indentation Rules.tmPreferences
```

SublimeErl looks like a cool plugin.  [SublimeREPL](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL#readme) also offers Erlang support.